# How to mearge one branch into another using GIT

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need the steps to merge all updated code present inside one branch into another existing branch using git. I am explaining my working steps below.

I have one branch as - `"Updated/All"` which I have cloned to my local directory.

Next I have already one branch name as `- product/changes`.

Here I need to merge that cloned `"Updated/All"` branch code to `product/changes` branch and then I will add some changes to `product/changes` after merging and push it. So what should be the proper git command steps for it.

Comment: What about `git merge product/changes` while you are already on the `updated/all` branch ? `git help merge` will give you tons of valuable info if you want to do more fancy things.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1) git checkout product/changes
```

This will switch you to the product/changes branch.

```
2) git pull Updated/All
```

This will merge changes from Updated/All to the product/changes branch.This won't switch your branch to Updated/All. you can do your changes to product/changes branch from here.

Comment: I added your first command from my local directory but it gave me `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` error.

Comment: have you initialized you repository using git init?

Comment: Why `pull` instead of `merge` ?

Comment: @HarryManoharan: No..now I am cloning `product/changes ` branch then I will checkout and pull.

Comment: @Zeitounator git pull is the same as git fetch + git merge. git pull will be convinient when working with remote repositories.

Comment: @user_agent you don't need to clone branches if they are from the same source branch. you can simply switch between branches using `git checkout`.

Comment: if your branch is in the remote repository and not in the local repo then you need to `git fetch origin <name of remote>` and then `git checkout` the branch.

Answer (score 0):

this might help: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

in your case you would do the following:

- `git checkout a` (you will switch to branch a)
- `git merge b` (this will merge all changes from branch b into branch a)
- `git commit -a` (this will commit your changes)

take a look at above link to get the full picture.